# Using chrome.mediaGalleries API to get the names of the user's galleries

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, html5-filesystem

I'm attempting to use the `chrome.getMediaGalleries` API to list the media galleries on a user's device. It works right up until the `item.name` part.

I watched a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9QSklqthit0&feature=youtu.be&t=10m31s) from the Google Developers youtube channel, in which they used `JSON.parse`. However, that throws an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 0` as to be expected. It's not JSON.

So my question to you is: how do I retrieve the human-readable (Videos, Music, etc.). Here is my code so far:

```
getGalleriesInfo(/*Array of DOMFileSystem objects*/ results) {

    if (!results.length)
        return console.log('No galleries found');

    console.log('Gallery count: ' + results.length);

    results.forEach((item, index) => {
        let gallery = item.name;// JSON.parse(item.name) doesn't work
        console.log(index, ' => ', gallery); // 0 => chrome-extension_hmnfbbnkjlgjgmlgpacnkkndfidbejpo_0:External_media_galleries-Default-hmnfbbnkjlgjgmlgpacnkkndfidbejpo-1, etc.
    });
}

// I'm using a custom element (document.registerElement)
createdCallback() {
    chrome.mediaGalleries.getMediaFileSystems({
        interactive: 'if_needed'
    }, this.getGalleriesInfo);
}
```

- The [`chrome.mediaGalleries` API docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/mediaGalleries)
- The [`DOMFileSystem` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem)
- [`JSON.parse` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) for good measure

Thanks,
Justin

EDIT: Chrome debugger view of `item`
[image: Chrome debugger view]
<sub>(source: [jtprogramming.com](http://jtprogramming.com/screen.png))</sub>

Comment: And what value of `item` do you see in the debugger when you set a breakpoint inside the function? The thing is, the code in the video doesn't make sense because DOMFileSystem API isn't JSON-based.

Comment: @wOxxOm I'm lost. Are you saying that there's no way to achieve my goal? In the Chrome docs, it talks about access to iTunes gallery, Videos, etc. How do I differentiate between them?

Comment: @wOxxOm I don't see anything there that I didn't already know but I'm not too familiar with chrome's debugger so maybe I'm missing something. I've included an image in the question of the sources panel with a breakpoint on `item`

Comment: Thanks for getting me on the right track @wOxxOm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chrome.getMediaGalleries API appears to have changed. To find the name of any given gallery you must use the [getMediaFileSystemMetadata](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/mediaGalleries#method-getMediaFileSystemMetadata) method.

```
_getGalleriesInfo(results) {

    if (!results.length)
        return console.log('No galleries found');

    console.log('Gallery count: ' + results.length);

    results.forEach((item, index) => {
        console.log(chrome.mediaGalleries.getMediaFileSystemMetadata(item));
    });
}
```

which returns an object with the metadata of the DOMFileSystem.

```
Object {
    galleryId: (string) int,
    isAvailable: boolean, 
    isMediaDevice: boolean,
    isRemovable: boolean, 
    name: "C:\example\path\to\gallery"
}
```